# Block search engines from all sites on Apache development server httpd.conf Header add/set X-Robots-Tag or <directory /> Header add/set X-Robots-Tag

Tags: apache, search-engine, httpd.conf

I'm looking for best practices or at least common practices. I need to tell search engines to not index any sites on my (RHL) Apache development server.
I see multiple ways folks have done this, but specifically I have seen to add to the httpd.conf file:

```
#(method 1)
Header add X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
```

Which does render the header I need, but I have also seen to add

```
#(method 2)
<Directory />
  # Globally disallow robots from the development sever
  Header Set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
</Directory
```

This also renders the header I need, (if both present this seems to overwrite the previous)

My question is, is there a significant difference between method 1 and method 2, and if so what is it?

If may also throw this sub question in too,
is:

```
Header set "noindex, nofollow"
```

enough or should the header be:

```
Header add "noindex, nofollow, noarchive, nosnippet"
```

Finally

```
Header set ...
```

or

```
Header add ...
```

ether one worked, is there any difference?

Forgive if too many questions I'll split up if needed here - but they are all related to best/common practices in my mind.

Comment: Quick follow up answer to one of my own my own questions - we have 15+ sites on same STAGING server all using the httpd.conf setting: X-Robots-Tag:noindex, nofollow, noarchive, nosnippet.   Accidentally in one site this was overridden by an entry in the .htaccess of just X-Robots-Tag:noindex, nofollow.  And that is the only site that showed in google - Sooo i would say that the full "X-Robots-Tag:noindex, nofollow, noarchive, nosnippet" is needed.

Comment: CORRECTION - missing "noarchive, nosnippet"  does not appear to be the issue. The site that was SHOWING in the index also had robots.txt with deny all, so google could not index to see to do 'noindex' on the site/page.  see  https://yoast.com/prevent-site-being-indexed/

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag#directives

Header set "noindex, nofollow"  is fine.